# How to display name, value and percentage in the legend?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

My chart is populated from the following:

```
    private class Data
    {
        public List<Row> Rows{ get; set; }
    }

    private class Row
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

And I plot a pie chart as follows:

```
    chart.Series.Clear();

    var series1 = new Series {
        IsVisibleInLegend = true,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
    };
    chart.Series.Add(series1);

    foreach (var row in data.Rows)
    {
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(row.Count, row.Count));
    };
```

In the legend I would like to display the Name, Count and Count as percentage. Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: This is entirely possible using the `Legends` property on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible; feel free to look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456711.aspx) regarding legends on chart controls (I'm assuming you're using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`).

> Legends enable people to distinguish between the series and data points in the chart picture. They are stored as Legend objects in the Chart.Legends collection property.

The `Legends` property is available in your properties pane, and when adding series to your chart, you can specify the legend text associated with it. The documentation provided above will demonstrate how to add legends programmatically at runtime.

Just in case the link ever dies out, the code is as below:

```
// Create a new legend called "Legend2".
chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend2"));

// Set Docking of the Legend chart to the Default Chart Area.
chart1.Legends["Legend2"].DockToChartArea = "Default"; 

// Assign the legend to Series1.
chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Legend2";
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
```

To get your values from a single series into the legend as separate labels, you'll have to get creative and essentially create two additional series that are empty. Then just set their `LegendText` property to the desired value.

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Name";
chart1.Series["EmptySeries1"].LegendText = "99";
chart1.Series["EmptySeries2"].LegendText = "30%";
```

As far as a straightforward method to add labels to the legend, I don't think it's possible. I believe the legend is built based on the `Series` property and it's associated legend properties.